# 18th century phrase, the "Great End"

Tags: phrases, expressions, early-modern-english

In the grant for the [Philips Academy](http://www.andover.edu/Pages/default.aspx) there is language which I find difficult to ascertain the real meaning.

[From the bottom of page 463 here](https://books.google.com/books?id=fbEVAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA463&lpg=PA463&dq=to%20lay%20the%20foundation%20of%20a%20School%20or%20Academy%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20instructing%20Youth,%20not%20only%20in%20English%20and%20Latin%20Grammar,%20Writing,%20Arithmetic,%20and%20those%20Sciences,%20wherein%20they%20are%20commonly%20taught;%20but%20more%20especially%20to%20learn%20them%20the%20Great%20End%20and%20Real%20Business%20of%20Living&source=bl&ots=H0WWoTrLR5&sig=cJ-9AlmFCMST3WTHhU5RTXV8oJo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIt_OA9u_rxwIVC3Y-Ch3OQg7z#v=onepage&q=to%20lay%20the%20foundation%20of%20a%20School%20or%20Academy%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20instructing%20Youth%2C%20not%20only%20in%20English%20and%20Latin%20Grammar%2C%20Writing%2C%20Arithmetic%2C%20and%20those%20Sciences%2C%20wherein%20they%20are%20commonly%20taught%3B%20but%20more%20especially%20to%20learn%20them%20the%20Great%20End%20and%20Real%20Business%20of%20Living&f=false)

> ...to lay the foundation of a free public School or Academy for the purpose of
>   instructing Youth, not only in English and Latin Grammar, Writing,
>   Arithmetic, and those Sciences, wherein they are commonly taught; but
>   more especially to learn them the **Great End and Real Business of
>   Living**

My question is, what does the **GREAT END** mean in this document. Is this a common 18th century phrase?

I feel the emphasized portion is ambiguous and informal, however the author clearly felt otherwise.

Comment: I'd read it as the 'ultimate goal' (in life), which presumably was quite clear in their minds and deemed to be the same for every student.

Comment: Note that it's the "great end" of "living".  Ie, the purpose of living.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **end**
>
> 4
>
> a :  an outcome worked toward :  purpose (the end of poetry is to be
>   poetry — R. P. Warren)
>
> **[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/end)**

Given that the school was founded in the late 1700s in America, it is almost certain that the 'great purpose' of life that is meant here is the Christian one of serving God.

EDIT

Here's another work from the 1700s that supports this conclusion:

> Which therefore is, or ought to be the **great End** of your eating and
>   drinking, and of all and every Action of your whole Life. As we learn
>   from his Apostle, faying, Whether therefore ye eat, or drink, or
>   whatsoever ye do, **do all to the glory of God**
>
> [The great necessity ... of publick prayer and frequent Communion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fKg7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22the%20great%20end%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwA2oVChMIlZ6wpozsxwIV1BfbCh1WTgBC#v=onepage&q=%22the%20great%20end%22&f=false)  By
>   William Beveridge  1709

Comment: I agree. I was writing an answer to the effect but I seem to have dozed off in the middle of doing. If you don't mind I just have several suggestions: One is to use a contemporaneous dictionary instead of Merriam-Webster's to define [end](http://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/?page_id=7070&i=697). In this case, the only reputed candidate is A Dictionary of the English Language by Samuel Johnson, published in 1755, just a few years after Phillip Samuel Jr's. birth. The other is to mention [great](http://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/?p=16557), since this is asking about both words together.

Comment: @Tonepoet - Using a dictionary of the time is an excellent idea. I hadn't considered that. I'm relieved to see that definition 13 of 'end' in the dictionary you cite is very similar to the present-day one I used. In the case of 'great' there is more than one possible definition that could be appealed to in this case.

Comment: I think people overestimate how much the language changed over the past few centuries since the dictionaries, education and the such started to stabilize it. Anyway, keep in mind that def. 14 follows from def. 13, so include that too. In fact, regarding the word "Great" all of the actual definitions are just several words each so it's not much hassle to include them all, omitting the exemplary quotes and using quotation marks instead of block-quotes.in order to maximize white<space. efficiency. Quotes might help end though and I have those transcribed if I could send them to you somehow.